# How to log the custom skipped test method details in report using TestNG?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created my own custom report and It looks good for smooth execution. When I had some code change in my application then some of test cases were failed, and skipped. But I can only logged the failure details in report not for skipped tc details. I have tracking the report based on test methods. Please, assume that I have 4 test methods in a class file,and I have 4 assertion points in each test methods. When the second method failed then the remaining methods need to skipped and It works as expected. But In report I didn't find any skipped test methods details. please can some one help me to resolve this. So far I didn't use any TestNG listeners to log the execution activity. I'm using my own report.

Answer (score 0):

When you use your own custom reporter, you should use [the logging reporters features](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters) and its appropriate listener: [`IReporter`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.9.6/org/testng/IReporter.html).

From `IReporter`, you should be able to find all the information you need. For example: skipped test methods:

[`ISuite#getResults()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.9.6/org/testng/ISuite.html#getResults()) -> [`ISuiteResult#getTestContext()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.9.6/org/testng/ISuiteResult.html#getTestContext()) -> [`ITestContext#getSkippedTests()`](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.9.6/org/testng/ITestContext.html#getSkippedTests())